# Why is Visual Studio not picking up my Class Libraries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a asp.net MVC 4 Application I'm working using visual Studio 2010.
I have added 3 Class libraries to the solution and for some reason only one of them is being picked up by visual studio.
So in any class where I reference the other in Using statement. I get the following error "The type or namespace name "*" does not exist in the namespace "MyProject"(are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I have right clicked on the main project, selected properties and checked that all the class libraries are listed under projects, which they are.

I have right clicked on the solution, selected properties and ProjectDependcies, and this is also set up correctly.

The class libraries are all listed in the References folder for the main Project.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding , no joy any suggestions ??? Thanks

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: There is quiet alot, what do you need ?

Comment: First, make sure they are targeting the same version of .NET. Then make sure  YOU are targeting the version of .NET you think you are (ex, .NET 4 is different than .NET 4 Client Profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLLs are likely built using an later version of the framework than your project is targeting.

Comment: How to confirm this, I know the class lib's are 4

Comment: This should be a comment rather an answer.

Comment: @mkell, use ILDASM and see the disassemble code. You will find it.

Comment: forgive my ignorance but I've never used ILDASM, (that I know of), how or where do I find/use it ?

Comment: To confirm what your current project is targeting, go into the project properties under the application tab.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is the possibility that the other two dlls have dependencies that you are not including as well?

Comment: @mkell,here is a good tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. BTW, you should check the MANIFEST file.

Comment: BY that , do you mean editing the dependencies through the solution, properties, Project Dependencies tab - cause thats not an option VS will not allow it.

Comment: @mkell No, I just mean simply including any required DLLs that these other two dlls may need in the bin directory. You wont have to add references to these additional dlls in the IDE.

Comment: just checked the bin folder for main project, the dlls for two class libraries are there, but not the one class library that was being recognised ?? and I also checked the content of the bin folder for the class library in the explorer on desktop, its empty.. make sense?

Comment: Embarrassingly the problem was also linked to the fact that the other projects did not have any classes in them, thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The version of .NET that your class libraries are targetting is greater than the version your application is targeting.

Either demote your libraries to use the version of .net targeted by your application, or promote your application to the version used by your libraries.